# append div value into url, along with user input from text field using Get submitting method javascript

Tags: javascript, url, get, append

i'm trying to add value of a div into the URL, then submit the form using GET so i can retrieve the data from the URL to display on my result page. But i'm not sure how to do that.

For example:
Code:

```
    <form action="Receipt.html" method="GET">
    <input type= "text" id="Name" name="txtName"/>
    <div id="total">30</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Purchase" class="submit"/>
     </form>
```

I need to pass the value of "total" along with Name to the URL when user hit submit button.
I hope that make sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I only hope that this URL doesn't specify how much a user needs to pay for a purchase...

Comment: Are you planning to do an ajax request

Comment: I am required to do this with javascript.

Comment: Roman - i'm not sure what you meant by your comment... It is a school assignment i am trying to learn. Therefore, the information doesn't have to be private.

Answer (score 0):

With use of jquery we can do this. Try this one...

Html:

```
<form action="Receipt.html" method="GET">
<input type= "text" id="Name" name="txtName"/>
<div id="total">30</div>
<input type= "hidden" id="txttotal" name="txttotal"/>
<input type="submit" value="Purchase" class="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Javascript: in document ready function

```
$('#txttotal').val() = $('#total').text();
```

In next page you can get `txttotal`

Comment: I am not at all familiar with Jquery, would you mind expanding the code a little bit more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can get your url from form by using:

```
var url = $("form").attr("action");
// add value
url+= "?divValue=" + $("#total").html();
// then you use jquery/ajax get as you planed.
```

Answer (score 0):

if your value in div is fixed or changes once so you can directly place in action, like

```
<form action="Receipt.html?total=30" method="GET">
```

Also, using ajax will be a better option if value changes with some changes in form.

Comment: the div value is not a fixed one, it changes depends on the user input. i was thinking about passing the value into a variable using getElementById and somehow stuck the variable into the URL. Not sure how to do this. *scratch head*

Comment: in that case it would be better to use AJAX. Simple and easy to implement.